# How can I clear the entire form client side or would the proper way be to call the controller and clear the model there?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I clear the entire form client side or would the proper way be to call the controller and clear the model there?

Notice that I have a partial view whose fields I would also want cleared.

This is the html.  The input (reset) button seems to only reset the values on that form. In this case the 3 checkboxes and none of the fields in the partial view.

For clarity the partial view has several Kendo textboxes and a dropdownlist.

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        @Html.Partial("_Registration", Model)
        <div class="text-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.Field1).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control text-center" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.Field2).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control text-center" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.Field3).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control text-center" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="reset" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" />
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple forms you could use a JavaScript to reset the other forms too.